# Безопасно ли передавать пароли и другие данные для авторизации через ajax запрос?

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Пишу регистрацию и авторизацию полноценную, и все это отправляется запросами AJAX то есть, что и пароли и все другие данные у меня через AjAX передаются. Вопрос: Безопасно ли это ? лично сам я сделал такое: в файлах обработчиках (куда идет запрос) я сделал проверку на метод передачи, если обратились через URL к файлу, то перенаправляет на главную, но мне сказали этого не достаточно, и что эти запросы нужно хешировать.

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, при некоторых условиях *любые* данные пересылаемые по сети могут быть прочитаны "третьей стороной".

Это может происходить:

- на стороне клиента перед отправкой пакета в сетевой адаптер ("шпионский софт" (например, антивирус, а вообще-то любой снифер));

- на стороне сервера после приема пакета ядром (тоже самое, в т.ч. при участии админа (или его попустительстве));

- на любом из роутеров между клиентом и сервером (действия админа);

- иногда прямо из LAN (если хаб/свитч позволяют, то с компа, включенного в этот сегмент (или наличии спец. оборудования в помещении));

Comment: но вы с этим ничего поделать не сможете) даже если вы закодируете, на стороне клиента, то можно будет раскодировать) если кодировка у вас не выполняется через AJAX))))

Comment: @manitikyl, а SSL? (для себя спрашиваю, интересно)

Comment: @Mantikyl, да да, ssl и аудентифицированный сервер, а для "надежности" cram-sha1 ещё в середине. и если вас после этого ломают, то у вас наверняка уже куча других проблем :)

Comment: С точки зрения безопасности нет никакой разницы между ajax-запросом и обычным запросом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если клиент по AJAXy обращается к скриптам - это безопасно). Единственное что может быть тут не безопасно что пользователь конкретно знает какой у вас скрипт обрабатывает информацию и вам его нужно максимально защитить от "искусственных" запросов.

Comment: можно более подробно об "искусственных запросах" ?

Comment: @Manitikyl, а если традиционным методом, то пользователь не может взглянуть на атрибут формы "action" и так же узнать, куда передаются данные. Так что ли?

Кстати, у меня в проектах, все данные передаются на морду сайта. Как вы в этом случае определите скрипт, который обрабатывает именно Ajax-запросы?

Comment: @Deonis, мы вроде разбираем конкретный случай, и я вроде нормально написал "Единственное что может быть тут не безопасно что пользователь конкретно знает какой у вас скрипт обрабатывает информацию", зачем спрашивать одно а потом переспрашивать другое? Вроде логично что пользователь всегда может контролировать что и куда он делает и посылает.

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, ну в худшем случае, если на ваш сайт зайдет какой нить школо-хацкер, будет пытаться обратиться к вашему скрипту напрямую, создавать CURL запрос например как самое простое, и POST методом(или с каким у вас там AJAX работает) пытаться послать запрос с SQLками например. ПОэтому все нужно фильтровать и если скрипт принимающий информацию а не выводящий, ставить систему защиты, проверка на родителя запроса(только ваш сайт) ну и если например регистрация то система капчи.

Comment: @Manitikyl, как-то пришлось посмотреть, куда один сайт ajax запросы посылает, чтобы написать автоматический мониторинг кое-чего) успешно всё получилось)